# Is there a shortcut for $(eval $(call ...)) in GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I keep writing `$(eval $(call some_function,arg1,arg2))` in my Makefiles. Is there a way to define `some_function` so that it can be used like `$(some_function arg1,arg2)`?

Comment: [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) being [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), you could download its source code (written mostly in C) and improve it. Alternatively, some `include`-d file in your `Makefile` could be generated. Even your `Makefile` could be generated (e.g. by [GNU automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), or your own program...)

Comment: There isn't a way to create such a shortcut.  If you're using call and eval lots and lots you might reconsider other ways to simplify your makefile.  Those are powerful tools that are intended to be used only sparingly for really complicated situations.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I was hoping a shortcut might exist considering how useful this is for avoiding code duplication in Makefiles. I can see how it might be useful to learn GNU automake; I haven't considered it before.